# How can I free memory?

Tags: c, memory, memory-leaks

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int * doall() {
    int *a;
    a=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*2);
    a[0]=2;
    a[1]=3;
    return a;
}
int main() {
    int *arr;
    arr=doall();
    for(int i=0;i<2;i++) {
        printf("%d ",arr[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    free(arr);
    return 0;
}
```

Is it possible to `free(a);`? Does `free(arr)` deallocate "a" in `doall` function?

In `doall` `a=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*2);`

Comment: Yes it will be deallocated.

Comment: `free(arr);` will free the memory allocated in doall()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it possible to `free(a);`

No. By the time `doall` finishes, there's no variable `a`, only its *value*. However, since this value is then assigned to `arr`, your program retains the reference to the block that `doall` has allocated.

> Does `free(arr)` deallocate `a` in `doall` function?

It does not deallocate `a` because at the time `free` is called variable `a` is already gone. However, it deallocates memory that has been previously assigned to `a`, so there is no memory leak.

Comment: Is it must to do `free(arr);` ?

Comment: @shibly Yes, you have no other choice as far as freeing `a`'s value after `doall` has returned. Otherwise you will get memory leak, because `doall` essentially transfers "ownership" of the memory block that it allocates with `malloc` to `main` function.

Answer (score 4):

Since the pointer returned by `malloc` is returned by `doall`, and `free` called on that, the memory *is* correctly deallocated.

Two points though

1. Don't cast the result of `malloc` in C. (You need to do that in C++.)
2. If you're using C++, use `new[]` and `delete[]` for managing array memory. Better still, use `std::vector`.

Answer (score 1):

When you call malloc, you get the address of the allocated memory returned. You store this in the local variable `a`, which will only exist for as long as the function is executing.

But when you `return a` you return a *copy* of that local variable, which the caller stores in the variable `arr`. This copy is taken before `a` goes out of scope.

`free` doesn't know or care about variable names. The only thing it cares about is that it gets an address which corresponds to one of the returned addresses from previous calls to malloc. Which it does in your case, so all is well.

Answer (score 0):

a is released once the function returns. In C, local variables are pushed onto the stack and popped off at return.